# Syntax Error: missing ; before *

Tags: c++, include-guards

When I try to run these headers:

*Direct3D.h*

```
#pragma once

//Library Linker
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")

//Includes
#include <d3d11.h>

//My Includes
#include "SimpleShaderRessource.h"


class Direct3D
{
public:
    Direct3D();
    ~Direct3D();

    bool Initialize(HWND);
    bool Run();
    void Shutdown();

private:

public:

private:
    ID3D11Device* g_pDevice;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* g_pDeviceContext;
    IDXGISwapChain* g_pSwapChain;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView;

    SimpleShaderRessource* g_pSimpleShader;

};
```

*SimpleShaderResource.h*

```
#pragma once

//My Includes
#include "Direct3D.h"

//Library Inludes
#include "CGE_Lib.h"

//Models
#include "Triangle.h"


struct SimpleShaderVertex
{
    CGE::Vector3D position;
    //CGE::Color color;
};

class SimpleShaderResource
{
public:
    SimpleShaderResource();
    ~SimpleShaderResource();

    bool Initialize(ID3D11Device*, ID3D11DeviceContext*, HWND, WCHAR*, WCHAR*);
    bool Render();
    void Shutdown();

private:
    void OutputShaderErrorMessage(ID3DBlob*, HWND, WCHAR*);

public:
    ID3D11InputLayout* g_pLayout;
    Triangle* g_pModel;

};
```

*Triangle.h*

```
#pragma once

#include "Direct3D.h"

class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle();
    ~Triangle();

    bool Initialize(ID3D11Device*);
    void Shutdown();


    ID3D11Buffer* g_pVertexBuffer;
    ID3D11Buffer* g_pIndexBuffer;

    UINT g_indexCount;
};
```

I got these errors from VS2015:

```
C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    simpleshaderresource.h  34  
C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    simpleshaderresource.h  34  
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   simpleshaderresource.h  34  
C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    direct3d.h  34  
C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    direct3d.h  34  
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   direct3d.h  34
```

But I don't see where those syntax errors should come from.
`#pragma once` should prevent circular includes so what did I wrong?

Comment: please unbold question body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as @marcinj pointed, there's a typo. In `Direct3D.h`, `SimpleShaderRessource* g_pSimpleShader;` doesn't match the class name `SimpleShaderResource`.

After fixing that it'll become a circular dependencies issue.

> `#pragma once` should prevent circular includes so what did I wrong?

No. [#pragma once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) is designed to guarantee the current file to be included only once in a single compilation. Preventing circular including is still your responsibility.

And you're including `"SimpleShaderRessource.h"` in `Direct3D.h`, and including `"Direct3D.h"` in `SimpleShaderRessource.h`.

It seems class `Direct3D` is not used in `SimpleShaderRessource.h`, so just remove `#include "Direct3D.h"` from `SimpleShaderRessource.h` (and `Triangle.h`).

It's a good habit to only include the necessary files.

Comment: Yeah that was the error. Thanks a lot. Gonna set it at answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: @Rafiwui You're welcome. BTW, include only what you need is a good habit.

Comment: Yeah normally I do so but in this case I included the `d3d11.h` in my `Direct3D.h` and didn't want to reinclude it in other ones because I had to write the `#pragma comment(...)` again. But a friend of mine told me to put them in the main and now it is cleaner. Thx for your help again.

Comment: @songyuanyao are you sure its caused by circular dependencies? OP has an error on line 34, and in Direct3D.h at this line there is `SimpleShaderRessource* g_pSimpleShader;`. In `SimpleShaderRessource` there is a typo : double `ss`. The class names is `class SimpleShaderResource`,

Comment: @marcinj I missed that typo...Anyway, after fixing it we'll still face circular dependencies. I'll add this to the answer...

Comment: Yeah that typo was because I copied the Direct3D.h first and then renamed it and then copied the other two headers

Answer (score 0):

In `SimpleShaderResource.h` you include some other headers upfront. If they contain any incompleteness/errors - compiler may encounter problems when analyzing the following code in `SimpleShaderResource.h`.
As these headers seems not to be external (you include them with "" , not < >), so they are probably yours. Check them carefully, or try to comment them out (program will not compile then, but perhaps it will be easier to find the guilty one; it is usually the last one included)